# Bash array contents get printed in columns

Tags: bash

```
$declare -a inputs=("(1 3 4 8 6 2 7 0 5)" "(2 8 1 0 4 3 7 6 5)"

$ for i in ${inputs[@]}; do echo $i; done;
```

gives

```
(1
3
4
8
6
2
7
0
5)
(2
8
1
0
4
3
7
6
5)
```

I want each array in a row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use quotes.  Say:

```
for i in "${inputs[@]}"; do echo $i; done
```

This would return:

```
(1 3 4 8 6 2 7 0 5)
(2 8 1 0 4 3 7 6 5)
```

---

Moreover, remove the `;` after `done` unless it's the last line in your script!

Comment: Liked the tip - found it useful in my script!

Answer (score 2):

Use quotes:

```
for i in "${inputs[@]}"; do echo "$i"; done;
(1 3 4 8 6 2 7 0 5)
(2 8 1 0 4 3 7 6 5)
```